# soap client with cxf: Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault

Tags: soap, client, cxf, stax

I am developing a SOAP client with Apache CXF. One method of the request returns me this stack in the client. With SOAPUI the same request returns me the expected response. Maybe I lost a library in JNLP? Maybe it is a binding problem?

```
2013-11-08 15:31:16,593 ERROR [es.isoftsanidad.eprescribe.comunclient.paneles.buscadorfarmacos.ListadoPF5Controlador] [setListaObjetos] Error en establecer el listado de los objetos
    javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
        at
    .....


Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1606)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logs on the server side.   This is the message that the server is sending back in it's SOAP fault.   Thus, something is happening on the server side that needs investigating.